# Getting duplicates from nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, duplicates

I'm fairly new to python and have the following problem. I have a nested dictionary in the form of

```
dict = {'a': {'1','2'}, 'b':{'5','1'}, 'c':{'3','2'}}
```

and would like to find all the keys that have the same values. The output should look similar to this.

```
1 : [a,b]
2 : [a,c]

..
```

Many thanks in Advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before we go to the solution, lemme tell you something. What you've got there is not a **nested dictionary** but rather **sets within the dictionary**.

Some python terminologies to clear that up:

- Array: [ 1 , 2 ]

  > Arrays are enclosed in square braces & separated by commas.
- Dictionary: { "a":1 , "b":2 }

  > Dictionaries are enclosed in curly braces & separate "key":value pairs with comma. Here, "a" & "b" are keys & 1 & 2 would be their respective values.
- Set: { 1 , 2 }

  > Sets are enclosed in curly braces & separated by commas.

  dict = {'a': {'1','2'}, 'b':{'5','1'}, 'c':{'3','2'}}

Here, **{'1', '2'}** is a set in a dictionary with key **'a'**. Thus, what you've got is actually set in a dictionary & not a nested dictionary.

### Solution

Moving on to the solution, sets are not iterable meaning you can't go through them one by one. So, you gotta turn them into lists & then iterate them.

```
# Initialize the dictionary to be processed
data = {'a': {'1','2'}, 'b':{'5','1'}, 'c':{'3','2'}}

# Create dictionary to store solution
sol = {} # dictionary to store element as a key & sets containing that element as an array
# Eg., sol = { "1" : [ "a" , "b" ] }
# This shows that the value 1 is present in the sets contained in keys a & b.

# Record all elements & list every set containing those elements
for key in data. keys (): # iterate all keys in the dictionary
    l = list ( data [ key ] ) # convert set to list
    for elem in l: # iterate every element in the list
        if elem in sol. keys (): # check if elem already exists in solution as a key
            sol [ elem ]. append ( key ) # record that key contains elem
        else:
            sol [ elem ] = [ key ] # create a new list with elem as key & store that key contains elem

# At this time, sol would be
# {
#     "1" : [ "a" , "b" ] ,
#     "2" : [ "a" , "C" ] ,
#     "3" : [ "c" ] ,
#     "5" : [ "b" ]
# }

# Since, you want only the ones that are present in more than 1 sets, let's remove them
for key in sol : # iterate all keys in sol
    if sol [ key ]. length < 2 : # Only keys in at least 2 sets will be retained
        del sol [ key ] # remove the unrequired element

# Now, you have your required output in sol
print ( sol )
# Prints:
# {
#     "1" : [ "a" , "b" ] ,
#     "2" : [ "a" , "c" ]
# }
```

I hope that helps you...

Answer (score 4):

```
dict = {'a': {'1','2'}, 'b':{'5','1'}, 'c':{'3','2'}}
output = {}

for key, value in dict.items():
    for v in value:
        if v in output.keys():
            output[v].append(key)
        else:
            output[v] = [ key ]

print(output)
```

And the output will be

```
{'2': ['a', 'c'], '1': ['a', 'b'], '5': ['b'], '3': ['c']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `defaultdict` to build the output easily (and sort it if you want the keys in sorted order):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = {'a': {'1','2'}, 'b':{'5','1'}, 'c':{'3','2'}}

out  = defaultdict(list)

for key, values in d.items():
    for value in values:
        out[value].append(key)

# for a sorted output (dicts are ordered since Python 3.7):        
sorted_out = dict((k, out[k]) for k in sorted(out))
print(sorted_out)

#{'1': ['a', 'b'], '2': ['a', 'c'], '3': ['c'], '5': ['b']}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can reverse the key-value in dict, create a value-key dict, if you only want duplicated values(`find all the keys that have the same values`), you can `filter` it:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def get_duplicates(dict1):
    dict2 = defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in dict1.items():
        for c in v:
            dict2[c].append(k)
    # if you want to all values, just return dict2
    # return dict2
    return dict(filter(lambda x: len(x[1]) > 1, dict2.items()))
```

output:

```
{'1': ['a', 'b'], '2': ['a', 'c']}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done using `defaultdict` from `collections`,

```
>>> d = {'a': {'1','2'}, 'b':{'5','1'}, 'c':{'3','2'}}
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dd = defaultdict(list)
>>> for key,vals in d.items():
...   for val in vals:
...     dd[val].append(key)
... 
>>>>>> dict(dd)
{'1': ['a', 'b'], '3': ['c'], '2': ['a', 'c'], '5': ['b']}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved with two inner for loops:

```
dict = {'a': {'1','2'}, 'b':{'5','1'}, 'c':{'3','2'}}
out = {}
for key in dict:
    for value in dict[key]:
        if value not in out:
            out[value]= [key]
        else:
            out[value]+= [key]

print out  # {'1': ['a', 'b'], '3': ['c'], '2': ['a', 'c'], '5': ['b']}
```